# Missing XPM icon on website

Tags: experience-manager, web8

We are currently upgrading a 2011 setup to web 8. At this moment we have troubles getting the XPM working. When we publish a page through the old publishing setup (deployers configured in CME) we get the XPM icon showing on that page. However when we publish that page through a target that is setup with the new Topology Manager setup, the icon just does no appear.

**This is our current Topology Manager setup:**

Topology Type

```
Name             EnvironmentPurposes     Id           ExtensionProperties
----             -------------------     --           -------------------
Staging Only     {Staging}               StagingOnly  {}
```

Cd Environment

```
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://<host>:8190/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"Anonymous"
IsOffline            : False
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : BestuurlijkeStaging
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Website

```
BaseUrls             : {http://<host>:8090}
CdEnvironmentId      : BestuurlijkeStaging
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        : 
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : WebBestuurlijkeStaging
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

WebApplication

```
ContextUrl           : /
WebsiteId            : WebBestuurlijkeStaging
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        : 
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : WebBestuurlijkeStaging_RootWebApp
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Mapping

```
CmEnvironmentId     : trddev
PublicationId       : tcm:0-5-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Staging
WebApplicationId    : WebBestuurlijkeStaging_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://<host>:8090/
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       : 
Id                  : Mapping1
ExtensionProperties : {}
```

Cm Environment

```
CoreServiceRootUrl     : http://<cmhost>/
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://<cmhost>/
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"MTSUser", "Password":"********"
Id                     : trddev
ExtensionProperties    : {}
```

**Discovery Service**

If we call http://:8190/discovery.svc/Environment/PreviewWebServiceCapability results in following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <entry xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" xmlns:data="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" metadata:context="http://<host>:8190/discovery.svc/$metadata#Environment/PreviewWebServiceCapability" xml:base="http://<host>:8190/discovery.svc">
  <id>http://<host>:8190/discovery.svc/PreviewWebServiceCapabilities('DefaultPreviewWebService')</id>
  <title></title>
  <summary></summary>
  <updated>2016-07-26T13:06:32.032Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name>SDL OData v4 framework</name>
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="PreviewWebServiceCapability" href="PreviewWebServiceCapabilities('DefaultPreviewWebService')"></link>
  <link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/related/Environment" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Environment" href="PreviewWebServiceCapabilities('DefaultPreviewWebService')/Environment"</link>
  <link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/relatedlinks/Environment" type="application/xml" title="Environment" href="PreviewWebServiceCapabilities('DefaultPreviewWebService')/Environment/$ref"></link>
  <category scheme="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/scheme" term="#Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.PreviewWebServiceCapability"></category>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <metadata:properties>
      <data:id>DefaultPreviewWebService</data:id>
      <data:LastUpdateTime metadata:type="Int64">1469519953168</data:LastUpdateTime>
      <data:URI>http://<host>:8390/ws/preview.svc</data:URI>
      <data:ExtensionProperties metadata:type="#Collection(Tridion.WebDelivery.Platform.PreviewWebKeyValuePair)"></data:ExtensionProperties>
    </metadata:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

**Business Process Type**

Our business process type uses the *StagingOnly* TopologyType. The Resulted Target Out of that is Staging (XPM).

Anybody an idea what I am missing? i thougth that XPM would be enabled if the Discovery service of the Cd Environment had a PreviewWebServiceCapability.

Kr,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the cause, a rather simple one.

We did an upgrade from 2011 SP1 Hr2 with DB copy. This resulted in the Default Templates being those of 2011 SP1 Hr2. We therefore needed to upload the new Trdiion.SiteEdit.Templating.dll with TcmUploadAssembly.exe. This solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your page source, whether do you have entry similar to as below:

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:12-2705-64","PageModified":"2015-11-12T14:03:56","PageTemplateID":"tcm:12-33-128","PageTemplateModified":"2016-04-26T11:57:25"} -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://AXWEB8.ams.dev:80/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>
```

Most likely you may not have above entry as you are not getting XPM icon. If that is the case check the following:

Prior to web 8 we used to mention the site edit url on the XPM TBB in page template, but from Web 8 we do not mention this url in new XPM TBB. Hence make sure that you have re-imported fresh XPM TBB's for web 8 via template builder and then also make sure to have session enable content web service.

**Prior to Web 8:**

```
  <Template xlink:href="tcm:1-39-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Enable inline editing for Page" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:F846A60E-96ED-4D37-A5C7-17ED8E9EDC43">
        <SiteEditURL>http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/</SiteEditURL>
      </Parameters>
    </TemplateParameters>
```

**After Web 8:**

```
 <Template xlink:href="tcm:1-39-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Enable inline editing for Page" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:F846A60E-96ED-4D37-A5C7-17ED8E9EDC43" />
    </TemplateParameters>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it was not the real cause but it helped finding it!